# Node:events 491 happening when trying to run loadtest -n 300 http://localhost:3000

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run a sample nodejs application I saw on a video tutorial, and it is about simulating traffic on a server. But when I execute the above command given by the proctor, it creates an error.

Here is my code

```
const numCpus = require("os").cpus().length
const cluster = require("cluster");
const { createServer } = require("http");


if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log(`This is the master process`, process.pid);
    for(let i = 0; i < numCpus; i++ ) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
    
}
else {
    createServer((req,res) => {
        const message = `worker process ${process.pid}`
        console.log(message);
        res.end(message)
    }).listen(3000)
}
```

and after I run

> loadtest -n 300 http://localhost:3000

this error shows up

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ENOTCONN
    at tryReadStart (node:net:674:20)
    at Socket._read (node:net:685:5)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:496:12)
    at Socket.read (node:net:741:39)
    at resume_ (node:internal/streams/readable:999:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -4053,
  code: 'ENOTCONN',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, have you tried to make a simple request or make `loadtest` to send only one request?

Comment: Yes.. Still gives the same error. I just want to add that the video I am watching is using a mac while I am using windows. Idk if that makes a difference